# SQL Server 2008 and the commandline tool bcp: are there different versions around?

Tags: sql-server-2008, bcp

I got the problem having written a little procedure to import some flatfiles in a table using openrowset...bcp... which didn't work at customers site.

A short check with bcp /? shows a different behaviour e.g. the switch -T was not trusted connection but rather something with Images.

Are there different versions of bcp delivered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer: It was the commandline-tool in a sybase environment. There are two management studio's side by side and the last one has set the environment-variable path...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are different versions of bcp for a specific SQL Server version.  And, the -T option as the trusted connection switch has existed in many SQL Server versions.

Are the SQL Server versions the same on each system? 
Are the bcp versions the same on each system (run `bcp /v`)? 
Can you give more information about what you see with the image-related output?

Comment: I will try to get the version-information of the bcp - tool at customers side.  It's a sql2008 installation.